# Can you block on a queue until an async task on the same queue is finished?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using a 3rd party API which performs a task on the main queue and then calls a completion block, which I provide.

I need to synchronously wait on that async task to complete **on the same queue** (main).

Is there any way to do this?  I can't think of a way, since the async task will never start, since I'll be blocking the main queue, waiting for it to finish.

Here's an example:

```
// I have no control over this API other than the callback
class SomeAPI {
    static func someAPIfunction(callback: () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // something important it does
            // ....
            callback()
        }
    }
}

// This is somewhere like an XCTestCase, where we're on the main queue
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
SomeAPI.someAPIfunction {
    group.leave()
}
group.wait()
```

Comment: What's wrong with doing the stuff you need to do after the task has finished in the call back?

Comment: In my case, I'm in an XCTestCase, so I need the async task to finish before I can assert on the side effects and continue with the test.

Comment: You can `XCTAssert` in the callback

Comment: And also, you might need to run a run loop in your test case so that the async call even happens

Comment: How do I keep the test from continuing and completing before the async task completes?  Also, in my actual use case, the callback is within my app, so it would be unfortunate to have to inject my assertions into the app.

Comment: Have you tried the example in the Testing With Xcode guide. The comment claims that `waitForExpectationWithTimeout` runs the run loop, so you won't deadlock https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH4-SW6

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was hoping for a non-XCTest specific solution if possible. The trigger for this call is a few away from the XCTestCase itself, so it's unfortunate to have to either pass self through those calls, or return a value back up to the test case, etc. It's unfortunate that responsibility/knowledge would be leaking.

Comment: You can spin, calling [`run(mode:before:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/runloop/1411525-run) as [shown here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/runloop/1412430-run). But if doing test case, you should do `waitForExpectationWithTimeout`. And if doing it outside test case, spinning run loops are code smell.